# No user information - what happens?

Tags: support, user-information

I just realized that there are questions and answers that are from "invisible users". I mean, I cannot find user information about them. There is no link to their page.
[See this question and the best answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727/how-to-get-locale-information-on-a-gwt-application)
Maybe this is well-known to you but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: The user does not exist; sometime this is because the question has been migrated from another site.

Comment: When question is migrated, there is a sign of it, I think. See my link. There's not such a sign.

Comment: Note the *sometimes*. Oded has given a more complete answer.

Comment: Before just removing my question consider keeping it because my link works but the other on the other question don't. (The linked user and the answer does not exist.)

Comment: closing != deleting

Comment: This was suggested me not long before that closed questions get deleted. :O

Comment: Many do, but that doesn't mean all of them do. And 1 close vote doesn't close the question... 4 more people needed to close it.

Answer (score 6):

We allow unregistered users to answer questions - through unregistered, they can still set a user name.

It is also possible that the user asked/answered the question on another Stack Exchange site where it was not suitable and it got migrated (and the migration destination doesn't have this same user registered).

Additionally, some users wish their accounts to be removed. We can do this and still keep the posts by removing the account, but not the post.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm surprised there are so many users like that.

Comment: @qben unregistered accounts get automatically deleted after a while without activity as far as I remember this explains the amount. Oded, is this correct?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yes. I don't recall the exact criteria off the top of my head.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd & @qben  - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/ ``